# Code wont run in function after other functions

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to get some code to run inside a function after a for/if loop in the function but the code isn't working. Look at the bottom of the code for 'Nothing runs here'.

```
function getClassListing(){
  var classSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = classSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = classSheet.getLastColumn();
  var classData = classSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();
  return classData 
}

function processForm(formdata) {
  var classArray = [];
  var personSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFilesByName(formdata.SomeName);
  var spreadsheetId = consumerSpreadsheet.next().getId();
  var personSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = personSheet.getLastRow();


  var classSpreadsheet = getClassListing();
  for (i=0 ; i<classSpreadsheet.length; i++){
    var spreadSheetID = classSpreadsheet[i+1][0];
    var formID = formdata.a[i];
    var className = classSpreadsheet[i+1][1];

    if (formID == spreadSheetID){
      classArray.push(formID);
      Logger.log('match');
      Logger.log(classArray.length);
    }
  }
    Logger.log('nothing runs here');
}
```

It seems if I hard code some data I get an error on the line:

```
var spreadSheetID = classSpreadsheet[i+1][0];
```

The error is TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 66, file "Code")

the hard coded data I used was a simple two dimensional array:
var classSpreadsheet = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]];

Don't understand why it would throw that error in the debugger but when I try to summit all my comparisons run just fine and even log on each loop. The only thing that doesn't work is that last Logger.log statement which I'd like to replace with some logic one it runs.

Comment: Is the script completing?  The EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT in the VIEW menu will show whether the script the completed, and if there was an error.  Also, use the debugger to step through the code.  [Troubleshooting Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: Last to lines: [15-08-10 18:46:36:672 PDT] Range.getValues() [0.131 seconds]
[15-08-10 18:46:36:674 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.69 seconds total runtime]. So Yes I think it does since it says so. However also sometimes the logs don't state anything at all and I'll have to retest with data.

Comment: Since this processes a form how do I step through this with the debugger? That is to say how to I add fake values when trying to step through the debugger for the function?

Comment: Can you share the source of function getClassListing() as well?

Comment: var personSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getActiveSheet(); -- you might try replacing active sheet with get by name or get by id

Comment: To use the debugger, you could "hard code" a variable with expected data from the form.  Are you using a Google form, or an HTML form?  Is the spreadsheet active when the code is run?

Comment: I am using an HTML form from HTMLservice. The spreadsheet is active but if it wasn't would that allow all the other code to run except that last Logger.log section?

Comment: I've added some more information to the post. Anyone know why I get the type error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is this line:

```
var spreadSheetID = classSpreadsheet[i+1][0];
```

the [i+1] is looking for the first column in a row that doesn't exist in the array, if that makes sense. Maybe leave it at [i]?

For instance, if you have placed 3x2 data into your classData you would have:

```
var classData = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
```

calling it would be:

```
alert(classData[0][0] + classData[0][1] ....... + classData[2][1]);
```

Your code here

```
for (i=0 ; i<classSpreadsheet.length; i++){
  var spreadSheetID = classSpreadsheet[i+1][0];
```

is looping 3 times starting [1][0] instead of [0][0] and ending at [3][1] instead of [2][1]. There is no classSpreadsheet[2][0] which is why it is bouncing out and not executing your last Logger.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks so much! I changed the code and now anything below it runs just fine.